# ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.19 - export map to PDF layers and attributes

Tags: pdf, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geospatial-pdf

Is it possible in an ArcGIS for JavaScript app, to export a map to PDF with layers and attributes, just like in ArcMap? 
In the [printtemplates](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/printtemplate-amd.html) export format in only see

```
pdf | png32 | png8 | jpg | gif | eps | svg | svgz
```

**Edit**: this is how it works in ArcMap, when you choose Export Map in the File Menu:
[image]

Comment: could you explain _pdf with layers and attribute_ ! for **layers** you mean legend ? and **attributes** you mean labeled features with attribute .

Comment: @bRIMOs - see updated answer